# Upload zip file in static resources

Tags: static-resources, upload, httprequest, heroku

I am making one project in which I send a file on Heroku via HttpRequest (including file in attachment) and I got response zip file now I want to store this zip file in static resources.

So how we can store zip file dynamically in static resources when we get zip file in HttpResponse?

Answer (score 1):

Static resources are accessible through the Metadata API. Your question doesn't really show how you're intending to use this functionality, but do know static resources [aren't intended to be changed much or used in high quantities as some form or file storage.](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_resources.htm)

> A single static resource can be up to 5 MB in size, and an
>   organization can have up to 250 MB of static resources, total.

Comment: I want to use apex class only without any api. Do you have an idea.